# How to call a book with a lot of pages?

Tags: word-request

A book with a lot of pages.

- Big book?
- Large book?
- Large volume book?
- Book with a lot of pages?

Comment: I think these would all work in this context. . . other possibille ajectives to describe a book with many pages are: thick, long, hefty, etc. There's no single way to say it.

Comment: I often use ***weighty tome.*** A bit affected, sure - but under what circumstances might you want to call attention to the size of a book *without* introducing an element of light-hearted facetiousness?

Answer (score 3):

Most of those would be acceptable, but my choice would definitely by "a long book" as that cannot be mis-construed - "big" or "large" might mean 'physically' in some cases.

Comment: A thick or heavy book would do. We can say 'a weighty tome' but that's a bit old-fashioned these days.

Comment: Both 'thick' and 'heavy' (and synonyms) only indirectly indicate the number of pages, and may be mis-leading in a few edge cases.

Comment: @MikeB - I think most people would know from the context that "thick" would refer to the number of pages in a book. "Hefty" is another we sometimes use in the UK.

Comment: A long book usually is physically large, unless it's printed on [Bible paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_paper)!

Comment: "Thick book" is often used - I don't see how it could be misleading in the vast majority of cases (and you could probably invent a "long book" that was of normal thickness, but 20 feet high and 5 inches wide, but that doesn't invalidate the general use of "long book").

Answer (score 2):

As a *massive book* may be used to block a door instead of being read, it's sometimes called **doorstop**.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the connotation you want to convey.  I think "thick book" is the best.

- **Thick book**: mainly implies **a lot of pages**, which is probably what you're looking for.  Example of "thick books" : old phone books, computer manuals, dictionaries
- **Big book**: refers more to the size (width and height) rather than the thickness, such as many [coffee table books](https://guestofaguest.com/new-york/books/15-coffee-table-books-every-fashionista-should-own) or [Art Museum books](https://store.metmuseum.org/books).  A second meaning of "big book" has to do with the coverage of the subject: "Big book of <*subject*>" implies that it offers everything we want to know about the subject.
- **Large book**: also refers mainly to the overall size, not necessarily the number of pages
- **Heavy book**: refers mainly for the weight.  Some books use thick paper, so can be heavy even though there are not that many pages.
- **Long book**: implies a book that takes a while to read from beginning to end, such as [*The Lord of the Rings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings) (1216 pages) which takes a *long time* to finish.
- **Volume**: refers to a book that is part of a collection, usually have volume numbers.  Example: [*Encyclopedia Britannica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica) 15th Edition which consists of 30 volumes.  A "Large Volume" wouldn't necessarily have a lot of pages.